# Regex, how to select everything except pattern?

Tags: regex, textwrangler

I'm working on TextWrangler, I want to delete every word from a text that doesn't have an hashtag before.
Example:

```
Looking for a simple #homemade gift for the #holidays? 
This #DairyFree #DarkChocolate #Fudge recipe is simple and absolutely delicious: http://sddf.us/fudge
```

I would like to have only

```
#homemade #holidays #DairyFree #DarkChocolate #Fudge
```

also I would like to use TextWrangler, because I know nothing about Java and PHP.
I used this regular expression `#\w+` which select the hashtag words, but I don't understand how to delete everything else.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all `(^|\s|[^#\w])+[^#\s]+` by empty strings.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR8xM0/3)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you find an answer useful, no need to say thanks, just mark the answer as accepted (i.e. click the checkmark to the left of the answer).

Comment: As this answered your question, please [accept it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/246338).